# Store user's state of app in mean stack application

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am using angular 9 and have forms with multiple parts.. like first section about name and personal details, second part about their primary school, third part about users past jobs, etc..
And each part has heading in a side menu.

> personal details

> primary school

> previous  job

Clicking on which user can go to that particular part of form..

The question is if the user, completes 2 parts i.e. personal details  and primary school and then exits the browser.. the next time when the users logs in.. the first thing I want to display is the 3rd form i.e. previous  job to the user.. so that he can continue  from there..
Conversely I also want to send an mail to the user stating 'please fill the previous job details in xyz.com'

How to store this kind of data.. can it be done by angular services or need to use NgRx store as must.. if ngrx is needed.. can I somehow store the state in some form in api..
I m using Express with mysql in backend..

Answer (score 0):

Ngrx store is mainly used to have consistant data in more than one component(like user name which should be same in header and profile component). for your scenario ngrx store is not needed, and one more thing, even if you want to use ngrx store when user closes data, you still have to store data in local storage or backend. so that you can use that data when user opens that page.

For your scenario use backend to store data. whenever he comes back to that page, first fetch data and fill it into fields.

Hope it helps. thank you